# Display an element when 50% of its height reaches the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Timothy Aaron](http://timothyaaron.com/js/fadein.on.scroll.js)'s code to display elements one by one while scrolling down.
It works well, but elements become visible only when their bottom is reached (which is causing issues for DIVs with significant height as people scroll down a white page for a while...). What should I modify in the code to have the `opacity: 1` applied already when 50% is reached (I mean 50% of the height of the element)? I tried `if( bottom_of_window > ( bottom_of_object / 2 )  ){` and `if( bottom_of_window > ( bottom_of_object - 50% )  ){` but both without success. See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGdkj/
Many thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Hide all elements outside the visible window */
    $('body *').each( function(){

        var top_of_object = $(this).position().top;
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window < top_of_object  ){

            $(this).addClass('hide').css({'opacity':'0'});

        }

    });

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of the desired elements */
        $('.hide').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();


                if( bottom_of_window > ( bottom_of_object + 20 )  ){

                    $(this).removeClass('hide').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

                }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle plz?

Comment: Sure, there you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mGdkj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of the desired elements */
    $('.hide').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() / 2;/*here is the change*/
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();


            if( bottom_of_window > ( bottom_of_object + 20 )  ){

                $(this).removeClass('hide').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

    }); 

});
```

Comment: Is there way to show this as a percentage? Is 20 the percentage? @Greg